# iphone rings through speaker with earphones connected

Tags: iphone, headphones

Just noticed that my iphone 8+ (ios 11.3) rings through speaker even when headphones are connected (works both with earpods and beats solo wireless). Is it a bug or a feature? Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

[This is normal, provided your ringer switch is set to ring.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208353)

Setting the ringer switch to silent will prevent the ringer from sounding from your phone's internal speakers, but not through external Bluetooth or wired speakers/headphones.